# Using {fmt} & source_location to create variadic-template-based logging function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, default-arguments, fmt

I'd like to create a simple log function in C++ which prepend the code location to the log message. I'd like to avoid macros overall as well as the usage of `__FILE__` & `__LINE__`.

Note that the `format` string is always a compile-time string, and I'd like to have a much computation as possible on compile time (the target machine is a small MCU).

I can use the C++20 [`source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) feature via `experimental/source_location`.
I can also use [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

I started off from [this](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#argument-lists). Currently, I've got the following:

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <experimental/source_location>

using source_location = std::experimental::source_location;

void vlog(fmt::string_view format, fmt::format_args args)
{
  fmt::vprint(format, args);
}

template <typename S, typename... Args>
void log(const S& format, const source_location& location, Args&&... args)
{
  vlog(format, fmt::make_args_checked<fmt::string_view, uint32_t, Args...>(format, location.file_name(), location.line(), args...));
}

#define MY_LOG(format, ...) log(FMT_STRING("{},{}, " format), source_location::current(), __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
  MY_LOG("invalid squishiness: {}", 42);
}
```

Which yields correctly `./example.cpp,20, invalid squishiness: 42`.

Looks to me like I'm pretty close. I think what's left is to make the `log` function take a default argument for `source_location` (I understand that `source_location::current()` as a default arguement is a good practice). I'm getting the following error though:

> :12:99: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'

Is this even possible to mix variadic templates and default arguments for parameters? If so, how?

Also, is there a way to prepend the `"{},{}, "` part to the compile-time `format` string to yield yet another compile-time string (to be used as format)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it with a struct that represents the format string and location:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <source_location>

struct format_string {
  fmt::string_view str;
  std::source_location loc;

  format_string(
      const char* str,
      const std::source_location& loc =
        std::source_location::current()) : str(str), loc(loc) {}
};

void vlog(const format_string& format, fmt::format_args args) {
  const auto& loc = format.loc;
  fmt::print("{}:{}: ", loc.file_name(), loc.line());
  fmt::vprint(format.str, args);
}

template <typename... Args>
void log(const format_string& format, Args&&... args) {
  vlog(format, fmt::make_format_args(args...));
}

int main() {
  log("invalid squishiness: {}", 42);
}
```

This prints:

```
./example.cpp:26: invalid squishiness: 42
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4aMKcW

Comment: But if you use `log(FMT_STRING("invalid squishiness: {} {}"), 42);` , it will not produce a compile-time error.

Comment: FMT_STRING is a legacy API and it won't compile when trying to pass to the log function: https://godbolt.org/z/z3zjxhYTP